# How to get RAM allocated memory in each app by programmatically from android?

Tags: android, performance, memory-management

I want to get all application ram memory in programmatically. I searched serveral times but I still don't have any solution. If any way to get the value for each apps.

Please anyone give me a solution, it's more help full for me.

Advance thanks...